# what command is used to create or modify multiple files with specified file size in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, operating-system, command

command 'touch "file{1..10}".txt' creates 10 files file1.txt, file2.txt .... etc. How can we also create multiple file with specific file size in this form.

**what I tried:**
*`fallocate -l 10M file{1..10}.txt`*

**Output**

```
fallocate: unexpected number of arguments
```

Comment: Nothing specific to Linux or Unix. However, the shell you're using is what resolves the `{1..10}`, so that is important. Adjust the tags (and read their description) to get better visibility here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `truncate` to extend the size of a file to a specific size

```bash
truncate -s 10M file{1..10}.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html), `fallocate` expects a single file name only.

You can use a loop:

```bash
for f in file{1..10}.txt
do
    fallocate -l 10M "$f"
done
```

or as a single line

```bash
for f in file{1..10}.txt; do fallocate -l 10M "$f"; done
```

Comment: isn't this a drawback (expects a single file name only)? we should be allowed to create at once. Anyways thanks for your response

Comment: @NikhithNikky It would probably run a bit faster if a single run of the program could handle all files compared to starting a new process for every file. You are free to suggest a change to allow multiple file names. Maybe you have to convince the program author(s)/maintainer(s) that this performance gain is important.

Comment: This one liner command didn't work for me :( . 
for f in new{1..100}.txt; do fallocate -l 10M "$f"; done
fallocate: fallocate failed: Invalid argument

Comment: @NikhithS The one-liner is the same code as the 4-line version. I cannot reproduce the problem. I copied the command from your comment, only changed the 100 to 10, and it runs as expected. Did you copy&paste the exact command that produces the error message on your system? Or did you maybe remove the error while re-typing it here? Use `set -x` to see what commands are actually executed. It should be `fallocate -l 10M new1.txt`, `fallocate -l 10M new2.txt` ... etc.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was, my filesystem being posix. So it didn't work. Adding --posix created the required files but the filesize was not set to 10M. with truncate it works well.